# "chfn: PAM: System Error" Intermittently in Docker Hub Builds

Tags: github, docker

Occasionally automated builds on the Docker Hub fail with PAM system errors like the following, which are from two separate builds:

```
     Preparing to unpack 
    .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ... 
    [91mchfn: PAM: System error 
    [0m 
    [91madduser: '/usr/bin/chfn -f MySQL Server mysql' returned error code 
     1. Exiting.
    [0m
    [91mdpkg: error processing archive 
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb 
    (--unpack):
     subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
    [0m

     Preparing to unpack 
    .../redis-server_2%3a2.8.4-2_amd64.deb ... 
    [91mchfn: PAM: System error 
    [0m 
    [91madduser: '/usr/bin/chfn -f redis server redis' returned error code 
     1. Exiting. 
    [0m 
    [91mdpkg: error processing archive 
    /var/cache/apt/archives/redis-server_2%3a2.8.4-2_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
     subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1 
    [0m
```

Interestingly, this failure only happens intermittently and with identical Dockerfiles. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 10):

There is a workaround! It's a simple fix and doesn't appear to have any negative repercussions. Add the following symlink to the top of your Dockerfile:

`RUN ln -s -f /bin/true /usr/bin/chfn`

Subsequent builds should succeed.

Comment: Unless you are trying to actually change the finger information about a system user, say for example to ensure emails from the mail user in `ssmtp` would match the site name running in the container.

Answer (score 9):

This is the result of some recent kernel updates (see [Github Issue #6345](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6345))

The kernel was recently updated to allow containers to send audit events, but they need CAP_AUDIT_WRITE to be able to write an audit event. (git-bisect was [used to track this bug down](http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/07/21/tracking-down-a-kernel-bug-wit/)

Before, PAM detected the auditing was unavailable/disabled (non-fatal error). Now that its available, PAM detects the auditing system and tries to use it, but fails writing the audit event (fatal error).

Possible Solutions:

1. Allow containers to have CAP_AUDIT_WRITE (the GitHub issue suggests this will be the default), but DockerHub doesn't let one grant this capability in their build system.
2. Disable Auditing Support in PAM. Someone has posted [docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sequenceiq/pam/dockerfile) for CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu 14.04 to rebuild PAM  and disable auditing. For a basic of how to rebuild PAM, you can look at the relevant Dockerfiles for [CentOS](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-pam/blob/master/centos-6.5/Dockerfile) and [Ubuntu](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-pam/blob/master/ubuntu-14.04/Dockerfile))
3. Disable `/usr/bin/chfn` by linking it to `/bin/true` (`ln -s -f /bin/true /usr/bin/chfn`)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

when performing an install of `mysql-server` on my `vagrant` `trusty64` box. i first tried to instal `mysql-server-5.6` but the installation hanged, had to reset the machine. than i tried the default mysql version but got the error above.

ended up destroying the virtual machine and creating a brand new one.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in samba container which uses net=host setting and uses bash script to create users with specified uid (to match host), e.g.

```
sudo adduser --no-create-home --uid 1000 --gecos "" --ingroup mysambagroup --disabled-password --disabled-login myusername
```

HTOK's solution worked perfect by just adding the following to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN ln -s -f /bin/true /usr/bin/chfn
```